# No funciona redireccionar en ZF2

Tags: zend

Ya sea con `$this->redirect()->toUrl` o con `$this->redirect()->toRoute`  no redirecciona cuando termino de editar un formulario, sino que queda la página en blanco sin ni siquiera mostrar algún error.

Revise todo, y la clase `UsersFilter` es la que da problema. Si comento todo lo que tenga que ver con la clase `$filter = new UsersFilter();` redirecciona sin problema, pero si lo dejo no funciona el redireccionar .

Este es mi código:

```
public function putAction(){

        $this->layout()->setVariable('page_header', 'Editar Usuario');
        $this->layout()->setVariable('page_description', 'Editar un usuario en el sistema');

        $form = new UsersForm("users_form");
        $this->dbAdapter =$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter');
        $users = new Users($this->dbAdapter);

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $filter = new UsersFilter();
            $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $data = $this->request->getPost();

                //Obtengo el token del usuario
                $actualUser = $users->getUserById($data['id_user']);
                $data['token'] = $actualUser['token'];

                //Creando un password seguro :)
                $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(array(
                    'salt' => 'Token unico: '.$data['token'],
                    'cost' => 5)
                );
                $data['pass'] = $bcrypt->create($data['pass']);
                $users->updateUser($data['id_user'], $data);
                //No funciona si se ejecuta el validador
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users');

            }

        } else {

            $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
            $user = $users->getUserById($id);
            $form->bind($user);
        }

        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'form'  => $form,
        ));

        return $view;
    }
```

Comment: Has probado a ir comentando de forma parcial las distintas funciones que tenga la clase `UsersFilter` para detectar que parte del código lanza el error?

Comment: Lo pude solucionar, era un error de dummy.

En la clase `class UsersFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface` al final del archivo cerré la llave así `?>` y después de eso habían 3 saltos de línea, los eliminé y funciono sin problema todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar, era un error de dummy.

En la clase `class UsersFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface` al final del archivo cerré la llave así `?>` y después de eso habían 3 saltos de línea, los eliminé y después de eso funciono todo sin problemas.